# VB.NET Service Click Once

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2017. I've added a windows service to this application and wrote the code for it. After I build and publish the solution there is no exe created for my service. Do i need the create a now project for this with Windows Service as type?

Comment: Each project can only output one assembly, i.e. DLL or EXE.  If you want a WinForms application and a Windows service then yes, you need two projects, although they can certainly be part of the same solution.  They probably should be if they are part of the same product.